# Bevel Shader Appears Inverted

Tags: texturing, texture-baking, normals, bevel

I am trying to create a simple rounded edge on a bunch of meshes but everything I have tried has resulted in the below image.

The steps taken are:

- Add Bevel Modifier.
- UV unwrap see image
- Add Bevel Node and Bake using cycles.

Everything looks perfect when viewing in cycles.

The problem is once done baking if I apply the normal to the mesh I get a huge seam in the center. It's as if the shading is inverted or being applied to each face rather than creating a rounded look on the edges.

[image: Render]

[image: UVMap]

[image]

Comment: Why are your UVs not merged? I see a separate island for each of your six sides. That doesn't seem right. Is your mesh possibly made up of six faces which are joined, but with vertices which are not merged? Go into Edit Mode and investigate this. If this is the issue, merge them by distance using Cleanup under the Mesh menu .  Then try UV unwrapping again, and baking your normal map again.

Comment: This was a simple cube that you get at the start using smart UV unwrap

Comment: With Smart UV unwrap, depending on the angle setting, it may split your UVs into too many islands. Try not using it in this case. Try using the standard UV unwrapping option. Just select all your faces in Edit Mode and press 'u'. What happens when you start this way?

Comment: If i follow these steps you get what my image shows.

1. Open new instance of blender
2. Apply bevel modifier to cube
3. Unwrap cube using smart UV unwrap and a .1 setting to margin and weight
4. Apply weighted normals and auto smooth

now visually i get perfect looking edges

5 Now i bake them and then apply the normal to the image like the image above and you get inverted shadows on the edges.

Comment: If you start with a brand new cube, it should have UVs generated by default. Those UVs will not consist of separate islands like your image shows. My question to you is, what happens if you start with a cube which has UVs like the one the default cube has? Do you get the same issues?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/nMCRL06.png

Same thing

Comment: Ive tried every bevel method i could find. Bevel Node, Bevel Modifier with Weighted Normal, Bevel Modifier with Hard Normal setting, High Poly Mesh Bake applied to low poly. Nothing seems to work, everything results in an inverted shading exactly like my images

Comment: Share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=QSxNV1k0" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/QSxNV1k0/)